# How to automatically shift portion of large set of math equation to next page?

Tags: align, amsmath

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[margin=1in,left=0.75in,right=0.75in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&\mathscr{F}_{1}\left(a_{3}V_{3}+V_{10}, V_{3}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{2}\left(V_{10}, V_{3}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{3}\left(\sigma V_{2}+V_{3}+a_{8}V_{8}+a_{9}V_{9}+V_{10}, V_{4}\right),\,\,\, \mathscr{F}_{4}\left(\sigma V_{2}+V_{3}+a_{8}V_{8}+V_{10}, V_{4}\right)\\
&\mathscr{F}_{5}\left(\sigma V_{2}+V_{3}+a_{5}V_{5}+a_{9}V_{9}+V_{10}, V_{4}\right),\,\,\, \mathscr{F}_{6}\left(\sigma V_{2}+V_{3}+V_{10}, V_{4}\right),\,\,\, \mathscr{F}_{7}\left(\sigma V_{2}+V_{3}+a_{9}V_{9}+V_{10}, V_{4}\right),\\
&\mathscr{F}_{8}\left(V_{3}+a_{8}V_{8}+\sigma V_{9}+V_{10}, V_{4}\right),\,\,\, \mathscr{F}_{9}\left(V_{3}+\sigma V_{5}+a_{8}V_{8}+V_{10}, V_{4}\right),\,\,\, \mathscr{F}_{10}\left(V_{3}+a_{9}V_{9}+V_{10}, V_{4}\right)\\
&\mathscr{F}_{11}\left(V_{3}+\sigma V_{5}+V_{10}, V_{4}\right),\,\,\, \mathscr{F}_{12}\left(V_{3}+\sigma V_{8}+V_{10}, V_{4}\right),\,\,\, \mathscr{F}_{13}\left(V_{3}+V_{10}, V_{4}\right),\,\,\,
 \mathscr{F}_{14}\left(V_{3}+\sigma V_{5}+a_{9}V_{9}+V_{10}, V_{4} \right),\\
  &\mathscr{F}_{15}\left(V_{3}+\sigma V_{8}+a_{9} V_{9}+V_{10}, V_{4}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{16}\left(V_{3}+\sigma V_{8}+V_{10}, V_{4}\right),\,\,\,
  \mathscr{F}_{17}\left(V_{3}+\sigma V_{5}+a_{8}V_{8}+V_{10}, V_{4}\right),\\
  &\mathscr{F}_{18}\left(V_{3}+a_{8}V_{8}+a_{9}V_{9}+V_{10}, V_{5}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{19}\left(V_{3}+\sigma V_{8}+V_{10}, V_{5}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{20}\left(V_{3}+\sigma V_{9}+V_{10}, V_{5}\right)\\
  &\mathscr{F}_{21}\left(V_{3}+a_{4}V_{4}+V_{10}, V_{5}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{22}\left(V_{3}+\sigma V_{8}+a_{9}V_{9}+V_{10}, V_{5}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{23}\left(V_{3}+V_{10}, V_{5}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{24}\left(2^{-1}V_{3}+V_{10}, V_{6}\right)\\
  &\mathscr{F}_{25}\left(2V_{3}+V_{10}, V_{1}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{26}\left(a_{3}V_{3}+V_{7}, V_{3}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{27}\left(V_{7}, V_{3}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{28}\left(V_{2}+a_{5}V_{5}+\sigma V_{6}+V_{9}, a_{5}V_{4}+3V_{5}+V_{8}+\sigma V_{11}\right)\\
  &\mathscr{F}_{29}\left(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}+V_{9}, \sigma V_{4}+3V_{5}+V_{8}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{30}\left(V_{2}+\sigma V_{6}+V_{9}, 3V_{5}+V_{8}+\sigma V_{11}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{31}\left(V_{2}+V_{9}, 3V_{5}+V_{8}\right),\\
  &\mathscr{F}_{32}\left(V_{2}+a_{5}V_{5}+\sigma V_{6}+V_{9}, 3V_{4}+\sigma V_{7}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{33}\left(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}+V_{9}, V_{4}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{34}\left(V_{2}+\sigma V_{6}+V_{9}, 3V_{4}+\sigma V_{7}\right),\\
  &\mathscr{F}_{35}\left(V_{2}+V_{9}, V_{4}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{36}\left(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}+V_{9}, V_{1}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{37}\left(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}+V_{9}, V_{1}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{38}\left(V_{2}+\sigma V_{6}+V_{9}, V_{1}\right),\\
  &\mathscr{F}_{39}\left(V_{2}+V_{9}, V_{1}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{40}\left(\sigma V_{4}+a_{5}V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}+V_{9}, \sigma V_{4}-a_{6}V_{6}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{41}\left(a_{4}V_{4}+\sigma V_{5}+V_{9}, V_{4}\right),\\
  &\mathscr{F}_{42}\left(a_{4}V_{4}+\sigma V_{6}+V_{9}, -a_{4}V_{4}+\sigma V_{6}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{43}\left(V_{4}+\sigma V_{8}+V_{9}, V_{4}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{44}\left(\sigma V_{4}+V_{9}, V_{4}\right),\\
  &\mathscr{F}_{45}\left(a_{5}V_{5}+\sigma V_{6}+V_{9}, V_{6}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{46}\left(\sigma V_{6}+V_{9}, V_{6}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{47}\left(a_{5}V_{5}+\sigma V_{6}+a_{8}V_{8}+V_{9}, 2V_{4}+\sigma V_{7}\right),\\
  &\mathscr{F}_{48}\left(a_{5}V_{5}+\sigma V_{6}+V_{9}, 2V_{4}+\sigma V_{7}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{49}\left(\sigma V_{5}+a_{8}V_{8}+V_{9}, V_{4}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{50}\left(\sigma V_{6}+a_{8}V_{8}+V_{9}, 2V_{4}+\sigma V_{7}\right)\\
  &\mathscr{F}_{51}\left(\sigma V_{5}+V_{9}, V_{4}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{52}\left(\sigma V_{6}+V_{9}, 2V_{4}+\sigma V_{7}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{53}\left(\sigma V_{8}+V_{9}, V_{4}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{54}\left(\sigma V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}+a_{8}V_{8}+V_{9}, V_{1}\right)\\
  &\mathscr{F}_{55}\left(V_{9}, V_{4}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{56}\left(\sigma V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}+V_{9}, V_{1}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{57}\left(\sigma V_{5}+a_{8}V_{8}+V_{9}, V_{1}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{58}\left(\sigma V_{4}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{9}, V_{1}\right),\\
  &\mathscr{F}_{59}\left(\sigma V_{6}+a_{8}V_{8}+V_{9}, V_{1}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{60}\left(\sigma V_{4}+a_{6}V_{6}+V_{9}, V_{1}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{61}\left(\sigma V_{8}+V_{9}, V_{1}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{62}\left(\sigma V_{4}+V_{9}, V_{1}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{63}\left(V_{9}, V_{1}\right),\\
  &\mathscr{F}_{64}\left(\sigma V_{5}+V_{9}, V_{1}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{65}\left(\sigma V_{6}+V_{9}, V_{1}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{66}\left(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}+a_{7}V_{7}+V_{9}, \sigma V_{4}+3V_{5}+V_{8}+a_{6}V_{11}\right),\\
  &\mathscr{F}_{67}\left(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}+a_{7}V_{7}+V_{9}, \sigma V_{4}+3V_{5}+V_{8}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{68}\left(V_{2}+\sigma V_{6}+a_{7}V_{7}+V_{9}, 3V_{5}+V_{8}+\sigma V_{11}\right),\\
  &\mathscr{F}_{69}\left(V_{2}+\sigma V_{7}+V_{9}, 3V_{5}+V_{8}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{70}\left(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}+a_{7}V_{7}+V_{9}, V_{4}\right), \,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{71}\left(V_{2}+\sigma V_{7}+V_{9}, V_{4}\right)\\
  &\mathscr{F}_{72}\left(a_{5}V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}+a_{7}V_{7}+V_{9}, -2a_{7}V_{4}+a_{6}V_{9}\right),\,\,\, \mathscr{F}_{73}\left(\sigma V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}+V_{9}, V_{9}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{74}\left(\sigma V_{5}+a_{7}V_{7}+V_{9}, V_{4}\right)\\
  &\mathscr{F}_{75}\left(a_{6}V_{6}+a_{7}V_{7}+V_{9}, -2a_{7}V_{4}+a_{6}V_{9}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{76}\left(a_{6}V_{6}+V_{9}, V_{9}\right), \,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{77}\left(\sigma V_{7}+V_{9}, V_{4}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{78}\left(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}, V_{4}\right)\\
  &\mathscr{F}_{79}\left(V_{2}+V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}, V_{4}+a_{6}V_{11}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{80}\left(V_{2}+\sigma V_{6}, V_{11}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{81}\left(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}, V_{4}+a_{6}V_{7}\right)\\
  &\mathscr{F}_{82}\left(V_{2}+\sigma V_{6}, V_{4}+\sigma V_{7}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{83}\left(V_{2}, V_{4}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{84}\left(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}, V_{1}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{85}\left(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}, V_{1}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{86}\left(V_{2}, V_{1}\right)\\
  &\mathscr{F}_{87}\left(V_{2}+\sigma V_{6}, V_{1}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{88}\left(a_{5}V_{5}+\sigma V_{6}+V_{8}, 3V_{3}+4V_{10}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{89}\left(a_{5}V_{5}+V_{8}, 3V_{3}+4V_{10}\right)
  \\
           &\mathscr{F}_{90}\left(\sigma V_{6}+V_{8}, 3V_{3}+4V_{10}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{91}\left(V_{8}, 3V_{3}+4V_{10} \right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{92}\left(\sigma V_{4}+a_{5}V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}+V_{8}, V_{7}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{93}\left(V_{8}, V_{7}\right),\\
           &\mathscr{F}_{94}\left(\sigma V_{4}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{8}, V_{7}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{95}\left(\sigma V_{4}+a_{6}V_{6}+V_{8}, V_{7}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{96}\left(\sigma V_{4}+V_{8}, V_{7}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{97}\left(a_{5}V_{5}+\sigma V_{6}+V_{8}, V_{7}\right)\\
           &\mathscr{F}_{98}\left(a_{5}V_{5}+V_{8}, V_{7}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{99}\left(\sigma V_{6}+V_{8}, V_{7}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{100}\left(a_{5}V_{5}+\sigma V_{6}+V_{8}, V_{1}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{101}\left(a_{5}V_{5}+V_{8}, V_{1}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{102}\left(V_{8}, V_{1}\right),\\
           &\mathscr{F}_{103}\left(\sigma V_{6}+V_{8}, V_{1}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{104}\left(V_{2}+a_{5}V_{5}+a_{7}V_{7}, a_{5}V_{2}+a_{5}^{2}V_{5}+a_{7}V_{11}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{105}\left(V_{2}+\sigma V_{7}, V_{11}\right),\\
           &\mathscr{F}_{106}\left(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}+a_{7}V_{7}, V_{5}+V_{8}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{107}\left(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}, V_{5}+V_{8}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{108}\left(V_{2}+\sigma V_{7}, V_{5}+V_{8}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{109}\left(V_{2}, V_{5}+V_{8}\right),\\
           &\mathscr{F}_{110}\left(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}+a_{7}V_{7}, V_{4}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{111}\left(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}, V_{4}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{112}\left(V_{2}+\sigma V_{7}, V_{4}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{113}\left(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}+V_{7}, V_{1}\right),\\
           &\mathscr{F}_{114}\left(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}, V_{1}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{115}\left(V_{2}+\sigma V_{7}, V_{1}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{116}\left(V_{1}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{8}, a_{5}V_{3}+V_{11}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{117}\left(V_{1}+V_{8}, V_{11}\right),\\
           &\mathscr{F}_{118}\left(V_{1}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{8}, V_{11}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{119}\left(V_{1}+V_{8}, V_{10}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{120}\left(V_{1}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{6}, 2V_{2}+(a_{5}-1)V_{9}\right),\\
           &\mathscr{F}_{121}\left(V_{1}+V_{6}, 2V_{2}-V_{9}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{122}\left(V_{1}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{6}, V_{7}\right), \mathscr{F}_{123}\left(V_{1}+V_{6}, V_{7}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{124}\left(V_{1}+\sigma V_{5}+V_{8}, V_{4}\right),\\
           &\mathscr{F}_{125}\left(V_{1}, V_{4}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{126}\left(V_{4}+\sigma V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}, \sigma V_{4}+a_{6}V_{11}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{127}\left(V_{4}+\sigma V_{5}, V_{4}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{128}\left(V_{4}+\sigma V_{6}, V_{11}\right),\\
           &\mathscr{F}_{129}\left(V_{4}+\sigma V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}, V_{9}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{130}\left(V_{4}+\sigma V_{5}, V_{9}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{131}\left(V_{4}+\sigma V_{6}, V_{9}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{132}\left(V_{4}, V_{9}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{133}\left(V_{4}+\sigma V_{5}, V_{7}\right),\\
           &\mathscr{F}_{134}\left(V_{4}+\sigma V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}, V_{7}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{135}\left(V_{4}+\sigma V_{6}, V_{7}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{136}\left(V_{4}, V_{7}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{138}\left(V_{4}+\sigma V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}, V_{1}\right),\\
           &\mathscr{F}_{139}\left(V_{4}+\sigma V_{5}, V_{1}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{140}\left(V_{4}+\sigma V_{6}, V_{1}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{141}\left(V_{4}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{7}, -a_{5}V_{6}+V_{11}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{142}\left(V_{4}+V_{7}, V_{11}\right),\\
           &\mathscr{F}_{143}\left(V_{4}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{7}, V_{2}+a_{5}V_{3}+V_{6}+2a_{5}V_{10}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{144}\left(V_{4}+V_{7}, V_{2}+V_{6}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{145}\left(V_{4}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{7}, 2V_{6}+V_{9}\right),\\
           &\mathscr{F}_{146}\left(V_{4}+V_{7}, 2V_{6}+V_{9}\right),\mathscr{F}_{147}\left(V_{4}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{7}, V_{8}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{148}\left(V_{4}+V_{7}, V_{8}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{149}\left(V_{4}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{7}, V_{1}\right),\\
           &\mathscr{F}_{150}\left(V_{4}+V_{7}, V_{1}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{151}\left(V_{2}+V_{5}, -V_{7}+V_{11}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{152}\left(V_{2}+V_{5}, V_{3}+V_{10}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{153}\left(V_{2}+V_{5}, -V_{2}+V_{8}\right),\\
           &\mathscr{F}_{154}\left(V_{2}, V_{11}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{155}\left(V_{2}, V_{10}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{156}\left(V_{2}, V_{3}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{157}\left(V_{1}+V_{2}, V_{4}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{158}\left(V_{1}+V_{2}, V_{3}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{159}\left(V_{1}+V_{2}, V_{11}\right),\\
           &\mathscr{F}_{160}\left(V_{1}+V_{2}, V_{7}+V_{10}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{161}\left(V_{1}+V_{2}, V_{5}+V_{8}\right)\\
           &\mathscr{F}_{139}\left(V_{4}+\sigma V_{5}, V_{1}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{140}\left(V_{4}+\sigma V_{6}, V_{1}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{141}\left(V_{4}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{7}, -a_{5}V_{6}+V_{11}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{142}\left(V_{4}+V_{7}, V_{11}\right),\\
           &\mathscr{F}_{143}\left(V_{4}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{7}, V_{2}+a_{5}V_{3}+V_{6}+2a_{5}V_{10}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{144}\left(V_{4}+V_{7}, V_{2}+V_{6}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{145}\left(V_{4}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{7}, 2V_{6}+V_{9}\right),\\
           &\mathscr{F}_{146}\left(V_{4}+V_{7}, 2V_{6}+V_{9}\right),\mathscr{F}_{147}\left(V_{4}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{7}, V_{8}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{148}\left(V_{4}+V_{7}, V_{8}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{149}\left(V_{4}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{7}, V_{1}\right),\\
           &\mathscr{F}_{150}\left(V_{4}+V_{7}, V_{1}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{151}\left(V_{2}+V_{5}, -V_{7}+V_{11}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{152}\left(V_{2}+V_{5}, V_{3}+V_{10}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{153}\left(V_{2}+V_{5}, -V_{2}+V_{8}\right),\\
           &\mathscr{F}_{154}\left(V_{2}, V_{11}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{155}\left(V_{2}, V_{10}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{156}\left(V_{2}, V_{3}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{157}\left(V_{1}+V_{2}, V_{4}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{158}\left(V_{1}+V_{2}, V_{3}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{159}\left(V_{1}+V_{2}, V_{11}\right),\\
           &\mathscr{F}_{160}\left(V_{1}+V_{2}, V_{7}+V_{10}\right),\,\,\,\mathscr{F}_{161}\left(V_{1}+V_{2}, V_{5}+V_{8}\right)
           \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\allowdisplaybreaks` -- but please consider to restructure this 'beast' of equation

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked as desired. By the way these equations are just for illustration purpose only.

Comment: I see - I was scared already :D

Comment: What sort of restructuring of equations you are suggesting, aren't these equations in proper format?

Comment: Using `gather`, `alignat*` etc.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong tool.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[margin=1in,left=0.75in,right=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{quotation}\raggedright\noindent
$\def\comma{,\penalty0 \quad}\binoppenalty=10000
\mathscr{F}_{1}(a_{3}V_{3}+V_{10}, V_{3})\comma \mathscr{F}_{2}(V_{10}, V_{3})\comma \mathscr{F}_{3}(\sigma V_{2}+V_{3}+a_{8}V_{8}+a_{9}V_{9}+V_{10}, V_{4})\comma \mathscr{F}_{4}(\sigma V_{2}+V_{3}+a_{8}V_{8}+V_{10}, V_{4})
\mathscr{F}_{5}(\sigma V_{2}+V_{3}+a_{5}V_{5}+a_{9}V_{9}+V_{10}, V_{4})\comma \mathscr{F}_{6}(\sigma V_{2}+V_{3}+V_{10}, V_{4})\comma \mathscr{F}_{7}(\sigma V_{2}+V_{3}+a_{9}V_{9}+V_{10}, V_{4})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{8}(V_{3}+a_{8}V_{8}+\sigma V_{9}+V_{10}, V_{4})\comma \mathscr{F}_{9}(V_{3}+\sigma V_{5}+a_{8}V_{8}+V_{10}, V_{4})\comma \mathscr{F}_{10}(V_{3}+a_{9}V_{9}+V_{10}, V_{4})
\mathscr{F}_{11}(V_{3}+\sigma V_{5}+V_{10}, V_{4})\comma \mathscr{F}_{12}(V_{3}+\sigma V_{8}+V_{10}, V_{4})\comma \mathscr{F}_{13}(V_{3}+V_{10}, V_{4})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{14}(V_{3}+\sigma V_{5}+a_{9}V_{9}+V_{10}, V_{4} )\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{15}(V_{3}+\sigma V_{8}+a_{9} V_{9}+V_{10}, V_{4})\comma \mathscr{F}_{16}(V_{3}+\sigma V_{8}+V_{10}, V_{4})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{17}(V_{3}+\sigma V_{5}+a_{8}V_{8}+V_{10}, V_{4})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{18}(V_{3}+a_{8}V_{8}+a_{9}V_{9}+V_{10}, V_{5})\comma \mathscr{F}_{19}(V_{3}+\sigma V_{8}+V_{10}, V_{5})\comma \mathscr{F}_{20}(V_{3}+\sigma V_{9}+V_{10}, V_{5})
\mathscr{F}_{21}(V_{3}+a_{4}V_{4}+V_{10}, V_{5})\comma \mathscr{F}_{22}(V_{3}+\sigma V_{8}+a_{9}V_{9}+V_{10}, V_{5})\comma \mathscr{F}_{23}(V_{3}+V_{10}, V_{5})\comma \mathscr{F}_{24}(2^{-1}V_{3}+V_{10}, V_{6})
\mathscr{F}_{25}(2V_{3}+V_{10}, V_{1})\comma \mathscr{F}_{26}(a_{3}V_{3}+V_{7}, V_{3})\comma \mathscr{F}_{27}(V_{7}, V_{3})\comma \mathscr{F}_{28}(V_{2}+a_{5}V_{5}+\sigma V_{6}+V_{9}, a_{5}V_{4}+3V_{5}+V_{8}+\sigma V_{11})
\mathscr{F}_{29}(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}+V_{9}, \sigma V_{4}+3V_{5}+V_{8})\comma \mathscr{F}_{30}(V_{2}+\sigma V_{6}+V_{9}, 3V_{5}+V_{8}+\sigma V_{11})\comma \mathscr{F}_{31}(V_{2}+V_{9}, 3V_{5}+V_{8})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{32}(V_{2}+a_{5}V_{5}+\sigma V_{6}+V_{9}, 3V_{4}+\sigma V_{7})\comma \mathscr{F}_{33}(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}+V_{9}, V_{4})\comma \mathscr{F}_{34}(V_{2}+\sigma V_{6}+V_{9}, 3V_{4}+\sigma V_{7})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{35}(V_{2}+V_{9}, V_{4})\comma \mathscr{F}_{36}(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}+V_{9}, V_{1})\comma \mathscr{F}_{37}(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}+V_{9}, V_{1})\comma \mathscr{F}_{38}(V_{2}+\sigma V_{6}+V_{9}, V_{1})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{39}(V_{2}+V_{9}, V_{1})\comma \mathscr{F}_{40}(\sigma V_{4}+a_{5}V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}+V_{9}, \sigma V_{4}-a_{6}V_{6})\comma \mathscr{F}_{41}(a_{4}V_{4}+\sigma V_{5}+V_{9}, V_{4})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{42}(a_{4}V_{4}+\sigma V_{6}+V_{9}, -a_{4}V_{4}+\sigma V_{6})\comma \mathscr{F}_{43}(V_{4}+\sigma V_{8}+V_{9}, V_{4})\comma \mathscr{F}_{44}(\sigma V_{4}+V_{9}, V_{4})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{45}(a_{5}V_{5}+\sigma V_{6}+V_{9}, V_{6})\comma \mathscr{F}_{46}(\sigma V_{6}+V_{9}, V_{6})\comma \mathscr{F}_{47}(a_{5}V_{5}+\sigma V_{6}+a_{8}V_{8}+V_{9}, 2V_{4}+\sigma V_{7})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{48}(a_{5}V_{5}+\sigma V_{6}+V_{9}, 2V_{4}+\sigma V_{7})\comma \mathscr{F}_{49}(\sigma V_{5}+a_{8}V_{8}+V_{9}, V_{4})\comma \mathscr{F}_{50}(\sigma V_{6}+a_{8}V_{8}+V_{9}, 2V_{4}+\sigma V_{7})
\mathscr{F}_{51}(\sigma V_{5}+V_{9}, V_{4})\comma \mathscr{F}_{52}(\sigma V_{6}+V_{9}, 2V_{4}+\sigma V_{7})\comma \mathscr{F}_{53}(\sigma V_{8}+V_{9}, V_{4})\comma \mathscr{F}_{54}(\sigma V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}+a_{8}V_{8}+V_{9}, V_{1})
\mathscr{F}_{55}(V_{9}, V_{4})\comma \mathscr{F}_{56}(\sigma V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}+V_{9}, V_{1})\comma \mathscr{F}_{57}(\sigma V_{5}+a_{8}V_{8}+V_{9}, V_{1})\comma \mathscr{F}_{58}(\sigma V_{4}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{9}, V_{1})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{59}(\sigma V_{6}+a_{8}V_{8}+V_{9}, V_{1})\comma \mathscr{F}_{60}(\sigma V_{4}+a_{6}V_{6}+V_{9}, V_{1})\comma \mathscr{F}_{61}(\sigma V_{8}+V_{9}, V_{1})\comma \mathscr{F}_{62}(\sigma V_{4}+V_{9}, V_{1})\comma \mathscr{F}_{63}(V_{9}, V_{1})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{64}(\sigma V_{5}+V_{9}, V_{1})\comma \mathscr{F}_{65}(\sigma V_{6}+V_{9}, V_{1})\comma \mathscr{F}_{66}(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}+a_{7}V_{7}+V_{9}, \sigma V_{4}+3V_{5}+V_{8}+a_{6}V_{11})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{67}(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}+a_{7}V_{7}+V_{9}, \sigma V_{4}+3V_{5}+V_{8})\comma \mathscr{F}_{68}(V_{2}+\sigma V_{6}+a_{7}V_{7}+V_{9}, 3V_{5}+V_{8}+\sigma V_{11})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{69}(V_{2}+\sigma V_{7}+V_{9}, 3V_{5}+V_{8})\comma \mathscr{F}_{70}(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}+a_{7}V_{7}+V_{9}, V_{4})\comma \mathscr{F}_{71}(V_{2}+\sigma V_{7}+V_{9}, V_{4})
\mathscr{F}_{72}(a_{5}V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}+a_{7}V_{7}+V_{9}, -2a_{7}V_{4}+a_{6}V_{9})\comma \mathscr{F}_{73}(\sigma V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}+V_{9}, V_{9})\comma \mathscr{F}_{74}(\sigma V_{5}+a_{7}V_{7}+V_{9}, V_{4})
\mathscr{F}_{75}(a_{6}V_{6}+a_{7}V_{7}+V_{9}, -2a_{7}V_{4}+a_{6}V_{9})\comma \mathscr{F}_{76}(a_{6}V_{6}+V_{9}, V_{9})\comma \mathscr{F}_{77}(\sigma V_{7}+V_{9}, V_{4})\comma \mathscr{F}_{78}(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}, V_{4})
\mathscr{F}_{79}(V_{2}+V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}, V_{4}+a_{6}V_{11})\comma \mathscr{F}_{80}(V_{2}+\sigma V_{6}, V_{11})\comma \mathscr{F}_{81}(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}, V_{4}+a_{6}V_{7})
\mathscr{F}_{82}(V_{2}+\sigma V_{6}, V_{4}+\sigma V_{7})\comma \mathscr{F}_{83}(V_{2}, V_{4})\comma \mathscr{F}_{84}(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}, V_{1})\comma \mathscr{F}_{85}(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}, V_{1})\comma \mathscr{F}_{86}(V_{2}, V_{1})
\mathscr{F}_{87}(V_{2}+\sigma V_{6}, V_{1})\comma \mathscr{F}_{88}(a_{5}V_{5}+\sigma V_{6}+V_{8}, 3V_{3}+4V_{10})\comma \mathscr{F}_{89}(a_{5}V_{5}+V_{8}, 3V_{3}+4V_{10})
\mathscr{F}_{90}(\sigma V_{6}+V_{8}, 3V_{3}+4V_{10})\comma \mathscr{F}_{91}(V_{8}, 3V_{3}+4V_{10} )\comma \mathscr{F}_{92}(\sigma V_{4}+a_{5}V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}+V_{8}, V_{7})\comma \mathscr{F}_{93}(V_{8}, V_{7})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{94}(\sigma V_{4}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{8}, V_{7})\comma \mathscr{F}_{95}(\sigma V_{4}+a_{6}V_{6}+V_{8}, V_{7})\comma \mathscr{F}_{96}(\sigma V_{4}+V_{8}, V_{7})\comma \mathscr{F}_{97}(a_{5}V_{5}+\sigma V_{6}+V_{8}, V_{7})
\mathscr{F}_{98}(a_{5}V_{5}+V_{8}, V_{7})\comma \mathscr{F}_{99}(\sigma V_{6}+V_{8}, V_{7})\comma \mathscr{F}_{100}(a_{5}V_{5}+\sigma V_{6}+V_{8}, V_{1})\comma \mathscr{F}_{101}(a_{5}V_{5}+V_{8}, V_{1})\comma \mathscr{F}_{102}(V_{8}, V_{1})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{103}(\sigma V_{6}+V_{8}, V_{1})\comma \mathscr{F}_{104}(V_{2}+a_{5}V_{5}+a_{7}V_{7}, a_{5}V_{2}+a_{5}^{2}V_{5}+a_{7}V_{11})\comma \mathscr{F}_{105}(V_{2}+\sigma V_{7}, V_{11})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{106}(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}+a_{7}V_{7}, V_{5}+V_{8})\comma \mathscr{F}_{107}(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}, V_{5}+V_{8})\comma \mathscr{F}_{108}(V_{2}+\sigma V_{7}, V_{5}+V_{8})\comma \mathscr{F}_{109}(V_{2}, V_{5}+V_{8})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{110}(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}+a_{7}V_{7}, V_{4})\comma \mathscr{F}_{111}(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}, V_{4})\comma \mathscr{F}_{112}(V_{2}+\sigma V_{7}, V_{4})\comma \mathscr{F}_{113}(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}+V_{7}, V_{1})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{114}(V_{2}+\sigma V_{5}, V_{1})\comma \mathscr{F}_{115}(V_{2}+\sigma V_{7}, V_{1})\comma \mathscr{F}_{116}(V_{1}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{8}, a_{5}V_{3}+V_{11})\comma \mathscr{F}_{117}(V_{1}+V_{8}, V_{11})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{118}(V_{1}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{8}, V_{11})\comma \mathscr{F}_{119}(V_{1}+V_{8}, V_{10})\comma \mathscr{F}_{120}(V_{1}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{6}, 2V_{2}+(a_{5}-1)V_{9})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{121}(V_{1}+V_{6}, 2V_{2}-V_{9})\comma \mathscr{F}_{122}(V_{1}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{6}, V_{7})\comma \mathscr{F}_{123}(V_{1}+V_{6}, V_{7})\comma \mathscr{F}_{124}(V_{1}+\sigma V_{5}+V_{8}, V_{4})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{125}(V_{1}, V_{4})\comma \mathscr{F}_{126}(V_{4}+\sigma V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}, \sigma V_{4}+a_{6}V_{11})\comma \mathscr{F}_{127}(V_{4}+\sigma V_{5}, V_{4})\comma \mathscr{F}_{128}(V_{4}+\sigma V_{6}, V_{11})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{129}(V_{4}+\sigma V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}, V_{9})\comma \mathscr{F}_{130}(V_{4}+\sigma V_{5}, V_{9})\comma \mathscr{F}_{131}(V_{4}+\sigma V_{6}, V_{9})\comma \mathscr{F}_{132}(V_{4}, V_{9})\comma \mathscr{F}_{133}(V_{4}+\sigma V_{5}, V_{7})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{134}(V_{4}+\sigma V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}, V_{7})\comma \mathscr{F}_{135}(V_{4}+\sigma V_{6}, V_{7})\comma \mathscr{F}_{136}(V_{4}, V_{7})\comma \mathscr{F}_{138}(V_{4}+\sigma V_{5}+a_{6}V_{6}, V_{1})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{139}(V_{4}+\sigma V_{5}, V_{1})\comma \mathscr{F}_{140}(V_{4}+\sigma V_{6}, V_{1})\comma \mathscr{F}_{141}(V_{4}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{7}, -a_{5}V_{6}+V_{11})\comma \mathscr{F}_{142}(V_{4}+V_{7}, V_{11})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{143}(V_{4}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{7}, V_{2}+a_{5}V_{3}+V_{6}+2a_{5}V_{10})\comma \mathscr{F}_{144}(V_{4}+V_{7}, V_{2}+V_{6})\comma \mathscr{F}_{145}(V_{4}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{7}, 2V_{6}+V_{9})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{146}(V_{4}+V_{7}, 2V_{6}+V_{9})\comma \mathscr{F}_{147}(V_{4}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{7}, V_{8})\comma \mathscr{F}_{148}(V_{4}+V_{7}, V_{8})\comma \mathscr{F}_{149}(V_{4}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{7}, V_{1})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{150}(V_{4}+V_{7}, V_{1})\comma \mathscr{F}_{151}(V_{2}+V_{5}, -V_{7}+V_{11})\comma \mathscr{F}_{152}(V_{2}+V_{5}, V_{3}+V_{10})\comma \mathscr{F}_{153}(V_{2}+V_{5}, -V_{2}+V_{8})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{154}(V_{2}, V_{11})\comma \mathscr{F}_{155}(V_{2}, V_{10})\comma \mathscr{F}_{156}(V_{2}, V_{3})\comma \mathscr{F}_{157}(V_{1}+V_{2}, V_{4})\comma \mathscr{F}_{158}(V_{1}+V_{2}, V_{3})\comma \mathscr{F}_{159}(V_{1}+V_{2}, V_{11})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{160}(V_{1}+V_{2}, V_{7}+V_{10})\comma \mathscr{F}_{161}(V_{1}+V_{2}, V_{5}+V_{8})
\mathscr{F}_{139}(V_{4}+\sigma V_{5}, V_{1})\comma \mathscr{F}_{140}(V_{4}+\sigma V_{6}, V_{1})\comma \mathscr{F}_{141}(V_{4}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{7}, -a_{5}V_{6}+V_{11})\comma \mathscr{F}_{142}(V_{4}+V_{7}, V_{11})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{143}(V_{4}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{7}, V_{2}+a_{5}V_{3}+V_{6}+2a_{5}V_{10})\comma \mathscr{F}_{144}(V_{4}+V_{7}, V_{2}+V_{6})\comma \mathscr{F}_{145}(V_{4}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{7}, 2V_{6}+V_{9})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{146}(V_{4}+V_{7}, 2V_{6}+V_{9})\comma \mathscr{F}_{147}(V_{4}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{7}, V_{8})\comma \mathscr{F}_{148}(V_{4}+V_{7}, V_{8})\comma \mathscr{F}_{149}(V_{4}+a_{5}V_{5}+V_{7}, V_{1})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{150}(V_{4}+V_{7}, V_{1})\comma \mathscr{F}_{151}(V_{2}+V_{5}, -V_{7}+V_{11})\comma \mathscr{F}_{152}(V_{2}+V_{5}, V_{3}+V_{10})\comma \mathscr{F}_{153}(V_{2}+V_{5}, -V_{2}+V_{8})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{154}(V_{2}, V_{11})\comma \mathscr{F}_{155}(V_{2}, V_{10})\comma \mathscr{F}_{156}(V_{2}, V_{3})\comma \mathscr{F}_{157}(V_{1}+V_{2}, V_{4})\comma \mathscr{F}_{158}(V_{1}+V_{2}, V_{3})\comma \mathscr{F}_{159}(V_{1}+V_{2}, V_{11})\comma 
\mathscr{F}_{160}(V_{1}+V_{2}, V_{7}+V_{10})\comma \mathscr{F}_{161}(V_{1}+V_{2}, V_{5}+V_{8})
$
\end{quotation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: \allowdisplaybreaks worked well as desired.

Comment: @mskalsi I'm sure about that; on the other hand, restructuring the code was very easy, leading to a better output.